On some properties of the quotient map in GIT
We say a group $G$ is reductive if whenever $V$ (a finite-dimensional vector space) is a representation of $G$, and $W$ is a subrepresentation, then there exists another subrepresentation $W^\prime$, such that $V = W \oplus W^\prime.$
Suppose $G$ is a reductive group, acting on an affine variety $X$. Then the algebra of invariant polynomials $\mathbb{C}[X]^G$ is finitely generated. Let $M$ be the affine variety whose regular functions are precisely this algebra, so that $\mathbb{C}[M] = \mathbb{C}[X]^G$. We call $M$ the GIT quotient of $X$ by $G$. There is then a map $\pi : X \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n \rightarrow M \subseteq \mathbb{C}^m$ which can be described as follows. Let $f_1, \dots , f_m$ generate $\mathbb{C}[M]$. Then $\pi(x_1, \dots , x_n) = (f_1(x_1, \dots  , x_n) , \dots , f_m(x_1, \dots , x_n))$.
I am trying to prove the following two claims.

$\pi$ is surjective.
$\pi(x) = \pi(y)$ if and only if $\overline{orb(x)} \cap \overline{orb(y)} \neq \emptyset$, where $orb$ denotes the orbit and closure is taken in the Zariski topology.

Mumford's book on GIT proves this in the language of scheme theory, which I am not versed in. Could someone point me to a proof using more elementary methods? Thanks.

Mukai's book Introduction to Invariants and Moduli might have a proof.

Thank you @TabesBridges for your comment. I looked at the book and indeed he does cover it in section 5. His proof of (ii) is clear. His proof that $\pi$ is surjective, essentially shows that its image is closed, but I'm not sure why the closure of $\pi(X)$ equals $M$.
